# Some doubts related to closed curves and simply connected space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have few  doubts.

(1) At  http://faculty.up.edu/wootton/Complex/Chapter8.pdf

I found the following result. The important part of the proof is what it says about the closed curve that it can be broken down into number of simple closed curve. If the examples given are of closed curves then i am confused what the following proof implies. Note that in the proof the fact that D is simply connected region (assumed to be open in the note) is not used to conclude that a closed curve can be broken down into a number of simple closed curve. My confusion is whether a straight line segment is a closed curve. I can see that there is a continuous surjective function from [0,1]to the line segment.

**Lemma 1.4**. Suppose C is a closed curve contained in a simply con-
nected region D. Then the interior of C is contained in D (by the
interior, we mean the finite region with boundary C).

Proof. Suppose that C is some closed curve. Then C may intersect
itself a number of times. However, if this happens, then C may be
broken up into a number of simple closed curves (see illustration)

(2) Whether the following definitions of simply connectedness are the same for $R^2$:

-a bounded subset E of $R^2$  is said to be simply connected if both E and $R^2\setminus E$  are connected. (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html)

-A space X (in particular X as a subspace of $R^2$) is said to be simply connected if it is a path-connected space
and if $π_1 (X, x_0 )$ is the trivial (one-element) group for some $x_0\in X$ , and hence for
every $x_0\in X$ . We often express the fact that  $π_1 (X, x_0 )$ is the trivial group by writing
$π_1 (X, x_0 )=0$. (Munkres Topology p.333)

(3) Is it true that a simple closed curve  in any simply connected space the interior of the curve is contained in the simply connected space.

Answer (score 0):

A closed curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$, is one where $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. Suppose $\gamma(c_0)=\gamma(c_1)$ then you can decompose the curve in $\gamma_0:[0,c_0]\cup[c_1,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma_1:[c_0,c_1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$. So supposing there is a finite number of self intersection you are ok.

The second question is harder bu you can google it, it requires a bit of algebraic topology.

The third question is false, because in a general simply connected space you cannot define an interior af a curve (e.g. think on a sphere). Although on the plane it it is true, and as proven in the notes, you just take one point $P\in Int(\gamma)\cap R$ and $Q\in Out(\gamma)\cap R$, where $R$ is the complement of your simply connected region. You join them by a path in $R$ and you find a point in $\gamma \cap R$ which is a contradiction because $\gamma$ was inside the simply connected region

Comment: I meant $R^2$ not any general simply connected space.